# Processing table data in Queue format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following is a main portion of the code from an SP that I am using to process table data in a FIFO queue order. The SP could be called by 100's of processes at the same time.

```
    create   TABLE #STAG(ident BIGINT)

    begin try

    begin tran
    insert into CaseLock (id,locktime,sessionid,lockid) output inserted.id into #STAG
    select top 1
         i.ident
        ,getutcdate()
        ,case when @sess is null then i.sessionid else @sess end
        ,newid()
      from QueueItem i WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)     where
        not exists(select 1 from CaseLock lck WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) where  lck.id = i.ident)
        and i.QUEUEIDENT    = @QUEUEIDENT       
        and i.finished is null and (i.deferred is null or i.deferred < getutcdate())   



    commit

    end try
    begin catch
       rollback
    end catch

    Select i.encryptid, i.id, i.ident, i.keyvalue, i.data, i.status, i.attempt
    from QueueItem i  WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) 
    where EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #STAG WHERE [#STAG].[ident]=i.ident)
```

The data in the QueueItem table can not be deleted, we use the CaseLock table to lock the record that has been selected for processing. Once a record has been procesed the finished column get updated to current datetime.

I am getting

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CaseLock'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.CaseLock'.  The duplicate key value is
>   (105).

My problem is the SP must always return a data, the application will crash if no data is returned from the sp.

How can I modify the code to resolve the Primary key violation error and it also returns a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute the following in two separate sessions (ssms query windows):

```
declare @QUEUEIDENT  = 12345 --a queue value which has rows for processing

begin transaction
    select top 1
         i.ident

      from QueueItem i WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)     where
        not exists(select 1 from CaseLock lck WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) where  lck.id = i.ident)
        and i.QUEUEIDENT    = @QUEUEIDENT       
        and i.finished is null and (i.deferred is null or i.deferred < getutcdate())
```

you will get the same value in both windows, that is why the primary key violation on CaseLock is raised (if the queries executed at the same time, they would try to insert the same primary key, one execution would succeed the other would fail).

The issue is with SELECT (ROWLOCK), the lock is not kept on the row after the row is read.
Another possible issue is with skipping any existing locks on CaseLock:

```
where not exists(select 1 from CaseLock lck WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
```

....assuming you delete rows from caselock when queue items fail processing (those queue items need to be retried later) you could end up with a queue reader trying to insert an item whose CaseLock is "on the flight" to deletion (the reader READsPAST any CaseLock locks on the deleted row).

In order to solve those two possible issues, you could try keeping the lock on QueueItem when reading and check CaseLock without any locks :

```
UPDLOCK on QueueItem keeps the lock for the duration of the transaction,
NOLOCK on CaseLock makes sure that i.ident will NEVER be inserted if it exists
```

``

```
 ...   from QueueItem i WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
 where
    not exists(select 1 from CaseLock lck WITH (NOLOCK) where  lck.id = i.ident)...
```

All this if you want to keep the existing implementation, checking the queue item processing status based on another table.
A simpler approach would be to have a process related column on QueueItem and update that column with READPAST (capturing the inserted.ident in turn etc).

Comment: Thanks for your help the UPDLOCK has helped. I am going to try the second approach you suggested and compare the performance of both.

Comment: could there be any performance impact? (NOLOCK might even be a bit faster). The suggestion of NOLOCK on CaseLock is for securing that a process will "NEVER" insert the same CaseLock twice.